How to install wxWidgets on Ubuntu 24.04
I need wxWidgets as I'm getting the error. But I couldn't make sure what repository do I need for wxWidgets and I don't know how to install it.
checking for wx-config... no
configure: error: 
        wxWidgets must be installed on your system.

        Please check that wx-config is in path, the directory
        where wxWidgets libraries are installed (returned by
        'wx-config --libs' or 'wx-config --static --libs' command)
        is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH or equivalent variable and
        wxWidgets version is 3.0.0 or above.


I did put the OS and releases in the header

The answer is acually quite, simply. Don't get confused by wxWidgets official website, as Ubuntu 24.04 Nolbe hasn't been mentioned. The following step worked perfect for me
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libwxgtk3.2-dev


Thank's it worked. Tested on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
